# Variable amount of Corners for a Polygon in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Busy fooling around with Tkinter, and was wondering if there was a way to create a polygon with a variable amount of corners? I'm trying to write a program that involves the user inputting a certain number of coordinates, and then a polygon with edges at those points is drawn on a canvas. Since I am unaware of the amount of values the user will input, it will be impossible to write code for every possibility, so is this actually possible?

```
canvas.create_polygon(x1,y1,x2,y2...xn,yn,fill="black")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an array of coordinates as long as they are pairs. eg:

```
# triangle
canvas.create_polygon([150,100, 100,150, 150,150], fill="red")
# square
canvas.create_polygon([0,0, 50,0, 50,50, 0,50], fill="black")
```

Comment: Wow, had no idea! Thanks!

Comment: Do the pairs have to be separated by spaces or be a second dimension within the array?